# how to use django collectmedia?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I have just downloaded the collectmedia snippet from http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1068/ but im not sure how to go about using it.

Where do i have to put it and how do i call it?

I now have:

```
- project
    - manage.py
    - mysite
- app
- management
    - commands
    - __init__.py
        - collectmedia.py
        - __init__.py
```

collectmedia shows up when i run ./manage.py -h but when i try to run it with :

```
./manage.py collectmedia
```

i get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Command'
```

Comment: In the upper right hand corner of that page you are given instructions. Place the file in `yourapp/management/commands/collectmedia.py` and run `manage.py collectmedia`. Or you can run `manage.py help collectmedia` for more options. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file and put it in a folder like:

```
-- your app /
---- management /
------- commands /
---------- __init__.py
---------- collectmedia.py
```

Run

```
./manage.py collectmedia
```

Also note:

```
This command includes an interactive mode (-i or --interactive) and a dry run mode (-n or --dry-run) for previewing what will happen. See manage.py help collectmedia for more options.
```

Comment: thanks i completely missed that. still not getting it running though, what should the contents of __init__.py be?, from collectmedia import *  ?

Comment: Just a blank file so that django recognizes it as a python module.